# Parse variable from system.log string and run command using parsed variable

Tags: scripting, variable, macos

My current solution works, but I know there is a better way to do this.

I run a tail of macOS system.log for keywords currently. I have a separate script for each keyword I'm searching for, then running the writestate command to reflect the keyword has appeared.

I would prefer to use a keyword trigger such as "scene name=[MOVIE]" that shows in the log, then parse MOVIE from the string and insert that into a variable to be then written as a state.

I have the following script written for each scene name created, but it would much cleaner to just have that value written into a variable then have the command ran when received.

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -F /var/log/system.log |
grep --line-buffered 'MOVIE' |
while read ; do ~/Applications/RacePointMedia/sclibridge writestate userDefined.ActiveScene MOVIE ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this awk statement to get stuff from mySQL.logs. I tweeked it for your string and log file.

I am not positive this will help you but sounds like it just might. 
This grabs the last line from your logs that contain the match and snags the last field into word_match. You can increment the {a=$0} to {a=$1} for first field, {a=$2} 2nd field etc.

```
`word_match=`awk '/scene name=\[MOVIE\]/ {a=$0} END{ print a }' /var/log/system.log | awk '{print $(NF)}'
echo $word_match #to display what you got.
```

Hope this helps